# ROR: Nested views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view, controller, nested

I have a page object and various template objects in my application. pages have names, descriptions urls etc and each have a relationship with a template.   templates have different numbers of content boxes and relationships with other controllers (like blogs, galleries etc.).

When I am rendering a page I can work out what template is attached to the page, and what the relevant content is based on that. but I am not sure what the best way is to render the nested Items.

Are you meant to somehow render the templates view from within the other view?  Or would you have to just rewrite the view altogether?   In this case would I have to create an extra template view for each different template, bundle it with the page views, and then only include it if it is the right one?

Would this be the same for galleries and blogs? do they all need to be bundled with the page? Or can it be called from its proper location?

I'm not sure what the best practice is here and haven't had any luck googling it. I'm suspecting that the key words im using aren't correct. Or this is common knowledge that isn't worth documenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shared partials to render views. Check out [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

In the views, you can render the partials based upon whatever condition you want.

For example:

```
- if params[:page] == "my_page"
  = render "shared/my_page"
```

Naturally, you will still need to set up the needed data in the controller.
Shared logic for this can be placed in the `Application Controller`.